# how to get started with jsGrid

Tags: jsgrid

I just discovered jsGrid and started using the "Basic Scenario" example at  "http://js-grid.com/demos/". This is after I followed the getting started at "http://js-grid.com/getting-started/".

To do my testing, ,I ended up with the html and js files below. Problem, NOTHING WORKED.

I cant get the Basic Scenario" table to show as it does in the demo.

Can anyone show what I'm missing?

Here is my understanding :
1. download the jsgris js and css files - I did this
2. you've got to have html with the div ""  - I did this
3. need js code to create the jsgrid object - I did this , (see my js code)

My understanding is that, in the demo example, the data source used is the "clients" array which is there the code.

What am I missing?

```js
    var clients = [
        { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
        { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
        { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
    ];
 
    var countries = [
        { Name: "", Id: 0 },
        { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
        { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
        { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
    ];
 
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        debugger;
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",
 
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
 
        data: clients,
 
        fields: [
            { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
            { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
            { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
            { name: "Country", type: "select", items: countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
            { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://js-grid.com/css/jsgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://js-grid.com/css/jsgrid-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>JSGrid and PHP Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>JSGrid and PHP Sample</h1>
</header>

<div id="jsGrid"></div>

<script>

</script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js-grid.com/js/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/sample.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't put a debugger; statement inside the object that you pass to jsGrid

Comment: ok tnx, I removed "debugger". All I get is "JSGrid and PHP Sample" and nothing more. I'm gonna keep trying.

If I can put the "debugger"  statement inside the object that you pass to jsGrid, how do I then debug jsGrid?

Comment: Your code works just fine, as you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzn73tc5/. As far as debugging goes, you should be using the tools your browser provides.

Comment: Tnx Trevor, yes I can see it works on jsFiddle. The problem was with the setup on my localhost. I've since solved that too. All I had to do was to set up a database on my local MySQL. I'm now customizing it for my iREPS app.

Thing is, the documentation is not clear on the set up procedure. I think the setup procedure must explain that for the "Basic Scenario" example to work, there must be a database set using the "createdb.sql" file in the directory "https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php/tree/master/db".